# Как называется такая конструкция /[0-9]{5}([- ]?[0-9]{4})?/?

Tags: javascript

Эта строка

```
var pattern = /[0-9]{5}([- ]?[0-9]{4})?/;
```

Весь код функции

```
function ZipCode(zip) {
   zip = new String(zip);
   var pattern = /[0-9]{5}([- ]?[0-9]{4})?/;
   if (pattern.test(zip)) {
      // значение почтового индекса должно быть первым совпадением в строке
      this.value = zip.match(pattern)[0];
      this.valueOf = function() {
         return this.value
      };
      this.toString = function() {
         return String(this.value)
      };
   } else {
      throw new ZipCodeFormatException(zip);
   }
}
```

Comment: Regular Expression  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: А конкретный экземпляр класса объект RegEx называют шаблоном

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего - Регулярное выражение